# IBM iSeries - getting information about job waits and DB via SQL sys views/tables

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400, health-monitoring

On IBM iSeries is there any way how to get information about

- job waits
- logical database I/O operations

from some of the DB sys views or tables?

I mean something similar like using QSYS2.ACTIVE_JOB_INFO for i.e. CPU information?

I went through IBM documentation, but cannot find it there.

Thank you

Comment: I don't see one either. You could write a stored procedure or table function to do that though.

Comment: I would look at the WRKJOB command. Just to see if the info you are looking for is displayed there.  Then you can look at the work management APIs https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/apis/wm1.htm to see about using code to retrieve WRKJOB information. From there you are writing an SQL procedure or table function to access that info from SQL.

Comment: there is also Scott Forstie's gists https://gist.github.com/forstie   He has posted a lot of examples of using SQL to access system information.